# How to make loop repeat until the sum is a single digit?

Tags: python

Prompt: Write a program that adds all the digits in an integer. If the resulting sum is more than one digit, keep repeating until the sum is one digit. For example, the number 2345 has the sum `2+3+4+5 = 14` which is not a single digit so repeat with `1+4 = 5` which is a single digit.

This is the code I have so far. It works out for the first part, but I can't figure out how to make it repeat until the sum is a single digit. I'm pretty sure I'm supposed to nest the code I already have with another `while` statement

```
n = int(input("Input an integer:"))
sum_int=0  
while float(n)/10 >= .1:   
    r= n%10
    sum_int += r
    n= n//10   
    if float(n)/10 > .1: print(r,  end= " + ") 
    else: print(r,"=",sum_int)
```

this is a sample output of the code

Input an integer: 98765678912398

8 + 9 + 3 + 2 + 1 + 9 + 8 + 7 + 6 + 5 + 6 + 7 + 8 + 9 = 88

8 + 8 = 16

1 + 6 = 7

Comment: Seems like an excellent opportunity to use recursion.

Comment: use an if statement and `len()`

Comment: Why are you having your program do all that arithmetic? Turn a number into a string, then turn each character into a digit.

Comment: For the termination condition: what can be said about the *numeric value* of a 'single decimal digit'? How can this be used in context? This can, and probably should, be solved without the use of floats or strings.

Comment: no more one digit like this? while n>9

Comment: this is for my python class, the reason its so complicated is because this is all we know so far so its the only way I can solve it and actually know what I'm doing

Answer (score 6):

This should work, no division involved.

```
n = int(input("Input an integer:"))
while n > 9:
    n = sum(map(int, str(n)))
print(n)
```

It basically converts the integer to a string, then sums over the digits using a list comprehension and continues until the number is no greater than 9.

Comment: You don't strictly need to send a list to `sum` - if you remove the brackets, it'll be a generator. Or, since the function you're mapping to is a built-in, you can just use `n = sum(map(int, str(n)))`.

Answer (score 3):

You could utilize recursion.

Try this:

```
def sum_of_digits(n):
    s = 0

    while n:
        s += n % 10
        n //= 10

    if s > 9:
        return sum_of_digits(s)

    return s

n = int(input("Enter an integer: "))
print(sum_of_digits(n))
```

Comment: *"You need to"* is put too strong: an iterative solution is also possible, and as this is a case of tail recursion, it is quite straightforward without recursion.

Answer (score 3):

you can try this solution, 
if n=98 then your output will be 8

```
def repitative_sum(n):
    j=2
    while j!=1:
        n=str(n)
        j=len(n)
        n=list(map(int,n))
        n=sum(n)
    print(n)
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to convert your integer to a float here; just use the [`divmod()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#divmod) in a loop:

```
def sum_digits(n):
    newnum = 0
    while n:
        n, digit = divmod(n, 10)
        newnum += digit
    return newnum
```

By making it a function you can more easily use it to repeatedly apply this to a number until it is smaller than 10:

```
n = int(input("Input an integer:"))
while n > 9:
    n = sum_digits(n)

print(n)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
def add_digits(num):
        return (num - 1) % 9 + 1 if num > 0 else 0
```

A simple, elegant solution.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it's anti-practice in Python because I know nothing about the language, but here is my solution.

```
n = int(input("Input an integer:"))

def sum_int(num):
    numArr = map(int,str(num))
    number = sum(numArr)
    if number < 10:
        print(number)
    else:
        sum_int(number)

sum_int(n)
```

Again I am unsure about the recursion within a function in Python, but hey, it works :)

Answer (score 1):

If you like **recursion**, and you must:

```
>>> def sum_digits_rec(integ):
        if integ <= 9:
            return integ
        res = sum(divmod(integ, 10)) 
        return sum_digits(res)

>>> print(sum_digits_rec(98765678912398))
7
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def digit_sum(num):
    if num < 10:
        return num
    last_digit = num % 10
    num = num / 10
    return digit_sum(last_digit + digit_sum(num))

input_num = int(input("Enter an integer: "))
print("result : ",digit_sum(input_num))
```

This may help you..!

Answer (score 0):

Try with strings comprehension:

```
new = input("insert your number: ")

new = new.replace(" ","")

new =sum([int(i) for i in new])

if new not in range (10):
    new = str(new)
    
    new = sum ([int(i) for i in new])

print (new)
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that the answers which convert int to str are relying on the python conversion logic to do internally the divmod calculations that we can do explicitly as follows, without introducing the non-numeric string type into an intrinsically numerical calculation:

```py
def boilItDown(n):
    while n >= 10:
        t = 0
        while n:
            d, m = divmod(n, 10)
            n, t = d, t + m
        n = t
    return n

n = 98765678912398
print(boilItDown(n))
```

Output:

```
7
```