# Sum of digits untill reach single digit

Tags: python

I set an algorithm which sum a number's digits but I couldn't make it till single digit. It only work for one step.

For example:

```
a=2, b=8
a^b=256 = 6+5+2 = 13
```

But I want to reach single digit, like:

`a^b=256 = 6+5+2 = 13 = 3+1 = 4`

Below you can see my codes.

```
a = int(input("Enter a value"))
b = int("Enter second value")

number = pow(a, b)
sum= 0
while float(number) / 10 >= .1:

    m = number % 10
    sum += m
    number = number // 10

    if float(number) / 10 > .1:
       print(m, end=" + ")
    else:
       print(m, "=", sum)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make loop repeat until the sum is a single digit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39551886/how-to-make-loop-repeat-until-the-sum-is-a-single-digit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this.

```
a = int(input("Enter a value"))
b = int(input("Enter second value"))

number = pow(a, b)
result = str(a)+'^'+str(b) + ' = ' + str(number)
while number > 9:
    digit_sum = sum(map(int, str(number)))
    result += ' = ' + '+'.join(str(number)) + ' = ' + str(digit_sum)
    number = digit_sum

print ( result )
```

for a=2, b=8 result:

```
2^8 = 256 = 2+5+6 = 13 = 1+3 = 4
```

Comment: Thank you, sir. Can you explain me what is not working with my code? And there is a point I did not understand about your code, can you please clarify it for me? I don't get the  int function here "sum(map(int, str(number)))"

Comment: You're welcome! your code needs an iteration until remaining one digit. but it's working just once. `sum(map(int, str(number)))` converts all digits to an integer list and sum.

Answer (score 6):

Here you go:

```
n = 256
while n > 9:
    n = sum(int(i) for i in str(n))

print(n)
```

So whats going on?  `str(n)` converts `n` to a string, strings in python can be iterated over so we can access digit by digit.  We do this in a generator, converting each digit back to a integer, `int(i) for i in str(n)`, we use `sum` to sum the elements in the generator.    We repeat this process until n is a single digit.

Added a solution that gives the calculation explicitly:

```
def sum_dig(n):
    _sum = sum(int(i) for i in str(n))
    explained = "+".join(list(str(n)))
    return _sum, explained
n = 256
s = ""
while n > 10:
    n, e = sum_dig(n)
    s+= f'{e}=' 

s += str(n)
print(s)
```

yields:

```
2+5+6=1+3=4
```

Comment: You may want to go `while n > 9:`

Comment: I think he wanted to print the formula itself. you're giving him only the result

Comment: Very elegant! You should also try to explain your code so that OP understands why your method works and learns something from it.

Comment: I see, then i misunderstood

Comment: I provided the correct formatting for OP's question. Largely based on this answer.

Comment: How to do this if the input is negative for example -1234 and I want output as -1 @ChristianSloper

Comment: Test for negative number at the start, run this code on the abs(n) and add back the sign at the end.

Answer (score 1):

This produces the output in the format OP asked for:

```
a = int(input("Enter a value: "))
b = int(input("Enter second value: "))

n = pow(a, b)
while n >= 10:
    nums = [i for i in str(n)]
    op = "+".join(nums)
    n = eval(op)
    print("{}={}".format(op, n))
```

## Logic:

1. Store the input in an array of individual numbers as strings.
2. Create the summation string using `"+".join(nums)` - for the output print.
3. Calculate the sum using `eval(op)` which works on strings (a built-in function) - store in `n`.
4. Print the summation string and what it equals.

## Output:

```
Enter a value: 2
Enter second value: 8
2+5+6=13
1+3=4
```

---

```
Enter a value: 2
Enter second value: 6
6+4=10
1+0=1
```

---

```
Enter a value: 2
Enter second value: 50
1+1+2+5+8+9+9+9+0+6+8+4+2+6+2+4=76
7+6=13
1+3=4
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sol = 0
if (a^b)%9==0:
    sol = 9
else:
    sol = (a^b)%9
```